# Custom error page not appearing on server

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

In my web.Release.config I have a custom error tag which I would have thought would redirect the user to the error page like it does on the localhost. However it gives me the Yellow screen of death instead. Anyone, know why?

Relase web config:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.cshtml"
        xdt:Transform="Replace" mode="On">
      </customErrors>
```

Standard web config:

```
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.cshtml" />
```

I know it isn't a lot of code but I'm not sure where to look for this so if you need more, just leave a comment and I'll add it.

Comment: Well from the look of it your release web.config and development web.config looks 1:1. Is the exception happening on Error.cshtml by any chance ?

Comment: No, whenever I try to enter a link which doesnt exist it just gives me the YSOD

Comment: Error.cshtml is in root of the application?

Answer (score 1):

remove defaultRedirect="Error.cshtml" from web.config as anyway you can not view cshtml from browser. just make on/off/readonly and it will work. Its partialview embedded in layout page when it renders.

Also make sure you are picking up correct profile while publish.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

1- Put the full view path:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml">
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

2- Redirect to a controller and the controller will return a view:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Home/Error" />
</system.web>


public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```